# how can i host sites on my pc with a domain?

Tags: web, hosting, web-hosting

Good evening.
I would like to host a site on a domain I bought online. The domain site gives me 2 options that I can change:
-record dns
-nameserver

Since I would like to host it from my pc, I don't know what to change.
Thank you

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [Can I create/host my own .com/.net domain name at home?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/123739/can-i-create-host-my-own-com-net-domain-name-at-home)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.